# Ubuntu does not boot properly. It only boots from recovery mode

Tags: boot, 20.04

I have dual booted my laptop with WINDOWS 11 and UBUNTU 20.04. But when I want to boot Ubuntu I can't. I have to go through the RECOVERY MODE in order to boot Ubuntu.
There is an error message attached to this.

Is there any solution?

P.S.

My laptop is a razer blade 15 2020

core i7-10750h

RTX 2070 MAx-Q

32 GB ram

512 GB SSD

2 TB SSD -> dual booted with Ubuntu and Windows 11

The Error message when I want to boot Ubuntu:
[image]

[UPDATE]

I tried and found the "SGX" in the boot menu. I enabled it. now there is another error `ACPI ERROR: NO HANDLER FOR REGION VRTC`. I don't know how to fix it. The problem with booting is still there. I still have to boot through RECOVERY MODE.

Comment: So it stays at the black screen and never boots into Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, that's the case. it never boots @ArturMeinild

Comment: Did it ever work? If yes, what happened between when it worked, and now when it doesn't work?

Comment: Do you "reboot" between Windows 11 and Ubuntu? Or do you "Shut down" between Windows 11 and Ubuntu? Do you have "Fast Boot" disabled? Windows likes to leave hardware in an unclean state, which can result in situations like this ...

Comment: No it never works. It only boots when I use RECOVER MODE. @ArturMeinild

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: @matigo I both do "Reboot" and "Shut down" but it does not help. I tried and disabled " Fast boot" but it won't help

Comment: I tried and found the "SGX" in the boot menu and enabled it. but not there is another error when I boot up Ubuntu. It says " ACPI ERROR: NO HANDLER FOR REGION VRTC" . What does it mean? How can I solve it?@ArturMeinild @matigo

Comment: @Mo.be make sure to add all the new information and additional explanations to your question so new readers don't have to look for important information in the comments.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community OP wants his Ubuntu to succesfully boot, so that he can use his computer with the Ubuntu OS installed on it. More specifically, OP wants to eliminate an error that prevents his operating system from booting succesfully.